# Calculating time complexity for simple programs

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I am new to programming and I came across this problem in my text book.

I have to find the worst case running time using Theta notation for this program :

```
1   i = 1, total = 0
2   while i < n/2 :
3       i = i*2
4       total = total + A[i]
```

What I understand is,
We need to see how many times each line is executed.

The first line runs only 1 time.

The while loop runs multiple times. (lines 2 to 4)
The while loop will stop when i < n/2.

And i is doubling up in each iteration of the loop (line 3).

So the total number of iterations will be sqrt(n/2 * 1/i) ?

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

if we suppose that a assingation, a adds, multiply or a condition is equal to 1. the result is 3 + 5n/2. Becuase, the loop entry 5 n / 2, and the last condition add the first assingnation is 3.

1   i = 1, total = 0             ->2

2   while i < n/2 :              ->1 + n

3       i = i*2                  ->2n

4       total = total + A[i]     ->2n

5 the loop is divided by 2.

Sorry if my grammar have mistakes, i am not native speaker.

Comment: how did you get 5n/2 ?

Comment: i have edited my post. i hope you looks with more clarity

Answer (score 0):

It will be `log(n)` (log base 2)

---

**Explination**: (This is going to be a little rough . . . )

1) Each iteration, you multiply `i` by `2` with `i=1` initially. After `x` iterations of the loop, `i = 2^x`.

So, the question is how many loop iterations `x` occur in terms of `n`? We know the terminating condition is when `i >= n/2`. We also know after `x` iterations, `i = 2^x`. We can thus substitute `2^x` for `i` to get the terminating condition `2^x >= n/2`.

Now we have an equation that we can solve for `x` in terms of `n`. . . .

`2^x >= n/2`  *terminating condition*

`log(2^x) >= log(n/2)`  *take log (base 2) of both sides*

`x >= log(n/2)`  *left-hand side simplifies to `x`*

When the number of iterations `x` is greater than or equal to `log(n/2)`, then the loop will terminate. So we expect the loop to run for `roof(log(n/2))` iterations. This gives us a big-O runtime of `O(log(n/2)) = O(log(n))`

---

Just noticed this is for big-theta, I'll leave this hear anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When we're studying time complexity of an algorithm, we're interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the function. Hence, we can without loss of generality assume that `n` is somewhat large (used in `n/2 - 1 ~= n/2` below).

Now, in the worst case scenario, the while loop just barely runs a final run; i.e. the loop is terminated after *after* iteration `i=n/2-1` has finished.

We can then study the number of iterations in the loop using sigma notation:

[image]

Hence, the algorithm runs in `Θ(log_2 n)`.